# init in MySQL url for Hibernate datasource

Tags: mysql, hibernate, schema, datasource, init

I am trying to create the schema name with my mysql (local database) url but its not working. Its working with H2 (in memory database) URL tho. Please advice.

H2 configuration -

```
 <bean id="datasource"
 class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
 <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
 <property name="url"
  value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=10;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS products" />
 </bean>
```

MySQL configuration - (Tried various combination of init to the below but will not work)

```
<bean id="dataSource"    
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="url"
value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
<property name="username" value="user" />
<property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

Thanks

Comment: Define "not working". Any error message in the console or in the logs?

Comment: Any follow up on that Roshini?